# How do I get a Windows Forms DataGridView to show new records when bound to EntityCollection

Tags: .net, winforms, datagridview, entitycollection

Trying to add new records to the EntityCollection at runtime and have the the DataGridView update with the new information.

I have tried bind the datagridview directly to the entity collection (i.e. ObjectSet) and through a BindingSource that is bound to the same collection.

I have tried DataGridView.Refresh(), DataGridView.EndEdit(), and BindSource.ResetBindings() among other things, but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

Try that:

```
bindingSource.DataSource = null;
bindingSource.DataSource = theCollection;
```

Alternatively, you could maintain a in-memory copy of the data in a `BindingList<T>`. Bind the DataGridView to the BindingList, and when you add an entity to the `ObjectSet`, add it to the `BindingList` too.

Comment: a.k.a. the ghetto way, :). Was hoping for a less brute force method. This doesn't work though cause I'm currently bound to a BindingSource. Which results in the grid being cleared.

Comment: Do entities not work well with DataGridView's? SO I need to keep 2 collections of the same data to get this to work?

Comment: @Jaime, you need to realize that an ObjectSet is not really a collection, it's actually a *query*. It doesn't keep the entities in memory (although the ObjectContext keeps a cache of already loaded entities)

Comment: Yea, I understand. I guess I thought the Entity folks would have come out with a solution or recommended way of databinding with entities. The whole point of databinding in forms was to simplify things, not make it harder.

Comment: Entity Framework isn't specifically designed for data binding... you could use it in a console app, or ASP.NET website. There's not reason for EF to care about data binding...

Comment: Sure there is. There moving toward using Entities for everything (at least from what I read), so it would would make sense to support binding with your leading data access solution. Maybe there just not there yet because of the youth of the framework. Seems to me its already in its 2nd or third iteration though...

Answer (score 0):

I am stuck with same problem. Microsoft should care about the people who use their technology and EF should care about data binding. Jaime, if you find a better way, please update this list. For me, recreating the context instance works fine for me. The funny thing is debugger shows that entity context & binding source has latest updates but datagridview still doesn't refresh. Thanks

[Here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/adodotnetentityframework/thread/6e1edbf2-b142-4aa7-a1c9-ae8d0b3d1495) is the best solution I have found so far -

Basically you need to do

```
bindingSource.DataSource = EntityContext.Collection
                               .Execute(MergeOption.AppendOnly);
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope it's not too late =) I have something that works here...

```
// Entity Data Model
private ManagerEntities context = new ManagerEntities();

// declare private member    
private BindingList<Currency> lstCurrencies = null;

// on form load, load data and bind to DataGridView's DataSource

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {

     lstCurrencies = new BindingList<Currency>();

     ObjectResult or = ((ObjectQuery)currencies).Execute(MergeOption.AppendOnly);
     foreach (Currency c in or)
         lstCurrencies.Add(c);

     // dgMain is my DataGridView
     dgMain.DataSource = lstCurrencies;
}

// this will save objects that have changed. You might want to add logic for newly created and deleted objects.
private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```